# Appmaker - Relation between local datasource and external datasource/Directory

Tags: google-app-maker

Trying to make a relational join between a local source (MyStaff) and the external datasource Directory (my company's directory).

However, there isn't an option to relate them.

Was hoping to create a local datasource with custom fields that I can "append" to user records from the existing Directory datasource.

Any help is appreciated.

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create relations between Directory Model and other model types. You have at least three ways to workaround this shortage:

**One**

Query directory records on the fly - this will okish work for single-record pages, but it will be tooo slow for lists.

**Two**

You can duplicate Directory fields you need in your tables.

Pros:

- it will NOT slow down your app
- it will let you to implement queries with mixed models data (Directory + Drive Tables or Cloud SQL)

Cons:

- You will store same data in two different places
- Eventually your version of Directory data will become stale

You can find nice sample of the second approach in
[People Skills app](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/people-skills/).

**Three**

Query Directory data on demand. Let's say you have databound list, and records bound to the list have UserEmail field. In this case you can:

1. Add some button to the list row
2. In button onClick event handler add code similar to this:

```js
app.datasources.Directory.query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = widget.datasource.item.UserEmail;
app.datasources.Directory.load();
app.showPage(app.pages.UserDetails); // or app.showDialog(app.pages.UserDetails);
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I think I'd pursue your third option to keep the app from slowing down and avoiding falling out of sync with the "real" directory datasource.

If you have any links to resources or examples of how to implement option 3 I would be very appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: Luis you are very welcome. I've added little bit more details for the third case.